# Swift App - Did not run at iPhone resolution when reviewed on iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, screen, screen-resolution

I have a swift universal app that I submitted and was approve the first time. However, when I submit an update and it got rejected because did not run at iPhone resolution when reviewed on iPad.
[image]

I know that I need to use auto layout to fix the issue, but it will take me a while to learn that. I need to submit the update as soon as possible to fix some bugs in the first version. Is there quick way to fix this? My app is a simple app with only text, button, no images. My main target will be iphone users anyway rather than iPad. Is that possible to scale the screen up when it is run on ipad. When I changed the device from "universal" to "iphone" in my app setting, and launched the app on ipad in the simulator, it actually scales up. However, it doesn't when I choose the universal.

I know in swift, I can use the following code to detect users on iPad, but I don't know how I can scale the screen up to fit on iPad. Thank you.

```
    UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad
```

Comment: If your app is a universal app then it is not supposed to run at iPhone resolution on the iPad. It should be a proper iPad app that uses the full screen of the iPad. If you really just want an iPhone app, change it to be iPhone-only instead of universal. Then put back iPad support in a later update after you've had more time to get that working.

Comment: If your app has already been approved and released as a universal app then you can't change it to iPhone only on a subsequent release.  Honestly, though based on the screen shot I am surprised your app got approved at all.

Comment: yah, I tried to launch iphone only, and it doesn't allow me. It was a mistake on my part to made it as an universal app. The app looks fine on iphone.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you will find a "quick-fix", but I'm not an expert on coding right now. This was the whole purpose of the Auto Layout features being implemented. AutoLayout allows your apps to scale independent of the device type you are using with a few caveats.

I know in SpriteKit game design you have a ScaleMode that can be set to .AspectFill, but I'm not entirely sure on just a regular View Controller without the AutoLayout.

Comment: yes, I understand that. I was wondering if there is a way to do that because when I set the "device" to iphone, and then launch the ipad, it actually scale up. That makes me wonder if there is a way to scale up in the code. I will try to learn how the auto layout work in the future and make it work, but that's not the priority for me right now.